# Best way to strike out a text

Tags: iphone, nsstring, uilabel

What is the best solution so far for a strike out text on the iPhone?

I heard of multiple solutions:

- Something with three20
- Image as a subview
- `UIWebView`
  And something with a `NSAttributedString`, but I don't find a working example for that.

Answer (score 10):

In iOS 6 we can use "NSMutableAttributedString" for use more different styles.

```
    NSString* cutText = @"This Line is strike out.";

    NSMutableAttributedString *titleString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:cutText];

    // making text property to strike text- NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName
    [titleString addAttribute:NSStrikethroughStyleAttributeName value:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:NSUnderlineStyleSingle] range:NSMakeRange(0, [titleString length])];

    // using text on label
    [myTextLabel  setAttributedText:titleString];
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try my solution of UILabel subclass, which supports:

multiline text with various label bounds (text can be in the middle of label frame, or accurate size)

- underline
- strikeout
- underline/strikeout line offset
- text alignment
- different font sizes

https://github.com/GuntisTreulands/UnderLineLabel